# How to compare a cell value with a string and count the frequency in hbase?

Tags: java, string, hbase

I am very new to hbase.

I have a two column family named as"name", "story type" and the values are like {Rajib,Clarke}, {photo,status,gif} respectively

I want to scan the rows of 'story type' when 'name' column has value "Rajib" and count the frequency of finding 'gif' with respect to "Rajib"

I have tried like below but this is not working. How can I  do that??
Thanks in advance..

```
    String columnfamily1="story type";
   int countgif=0;
    for (Result res: scanner)
    {

    if(Bytes.toString(res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(columnfamily),null))=="Clarke"){   
 if(Bytes.toString(res.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(columnfamily1),null))=="gif"){
                countgif=countgif+1;
                }
            }
        }
  system.out.printf("%d",countgif);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can you put some sample data so it will be clear about your requirement.
As I understood from your question you need to filter those rows which has name as 'clarke' and story-type as 'gif'.
This can be implemented using Scan class with additional filters as

SingleColumnValueFilter filter_by_name = new SingleColumnValueFilter( 
                   Bytes.toBytes("name" ),
                   Bytes.toBytes("name"),
                   CompareOp.EQUAL,
                   Bytes.toBytes("clarke"));
SingleColumnValueFilter filter_by_story = new SingleColumnValueFilter( 
                   Bytes.toBytes("story_type" ),
                   Bytes.toBytes("type"),
                   CompareOp.EQUAL,
                   Bytes.toBytes("gif"));

FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
filterList.addFilter(filter_by_name);
filterList.addFilter(filter_by_story);

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(filterList);

ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
Result result = scanner.next;

// now use iteration to print the complete value.. if you are interested only in count then just iterate and increment count
int gifCount =0;
while(result != null)
{
  gifCount ++;
result =scanner.next;
}
println(gifCount);
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. 
But it is returning the number of total rows without filtering